# 彼女は名誉な美食の宗教で育って、それを現代の基準に適応する方法を知っていた。このように、傑作が出られます

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese

So I have seen this relatively intricate sentence on a website and tried to translate it into Japanese, but at this point I have no other way to know if it's any good.

Here is the original sentence in French:

> Elle a grandi dans la religion de la gastronomie de prestige qu'elle a su adapter à l'époque actuelle, si bien que de sa cuisine peuvent sortir des chefs-d'œuvre.

It's translation in English: (not mine)

> She grew up in the religion of the prestigious gastronomy which she updated to nowadays standard, so that master pieces can come out of her kitchen.

Since there is no context, I thought it would be correct to put "彼女は". Here's my attempt:

> 「彼女は名誉な美食の宗教で育って、それを現代の基準に適応する方法を知っていた。このように、傑作が出られます。」

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some points

1. 宗教 means religion in the sense of spiritual activity and it doesn't make sense here. 流派 or something would work.
2. Inanimate subjects ("masterpieces" in this case) don't take potential verbs. "Can come out" should be translated into just 出る, 出て来る or できる (note; not potential) instead of 出られる here.
3. 名誉な almost only modifies one's act/behavior or events  and means "honorable".
4. A so that B is rendered into AのでB or BようにA.

With these things put together, I'd write

> 彼女は高名な美食の流派で育ち、それを現代の基準に適応させる方法を知っていたので（このように）自分の厨房から傑作が出るのだ。